# Simple JSP + PI4J - GPIO Pins (several) Already Exists

Tags: java, jsp, gpio

<strike>Happy **New Year** Everyone.</strike>

English is not my native language so please be patient.

I'm trying to use a Raspberry Pi 2 (Model B) for alert me when some one open the case, using a [limit switch](https://paletosdelaelectronica.files.wordpress.com/2015/01/fdc.jpg) and the GPIO pins. (This is not a Raspberry SE question)

At this moment I'm facing an issue with the GPIO pins, after following the [pi4j examples](http://pi4j.com/example/listener.html) (ListenGPIOExample.java) in console I tried to do in a web app; I'm using Apache Tomcat 7 (as root) and a **very simple JSP** page developed in netbeans for turn off/on a led. My code is the following:

```
<%@page import="com.pi4j.io.gpio.*"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8" import="RPI.GPIO"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="POST">
        <input type="submit" name="button" value="Button 1" />
        <%

        final GpioController gpio = GpioFactory.getInstance();

        final GpioPinDigitalOutput pin = gpio.provisionDigitalOutputPin(RaspiPin.GPIO_00, "MyLED", PinState.LOW);
        if (request.getParameter("button") != null) {
         try{
            out.println("NO Error");
            pin.toggle();
            Thread.sleep(500);
            pin.setShutdownOptions(true, PinState.LOW, PinPullResistance.OFF);

            //gpio.shutdown();
            //gpio.unprovisionPin(pin);
        }
        catch(Exception ex){
             out.println("Error");
        }
        } else {}            
        %>
    </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

If I push the button, it's suposed to change the pin state, but whenever I try got the same error, `HTTP 500 - com.pi4j.io.gpio.exception.GpioPinExistsException: This GPIO pin already exists: GPIO 0`. Tried with **several** pins, same error.

As you can see in the code, the unprovision and the shutdown are commented, because the solutions post in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28425918/this-gpio-pin-already-exists-gpio-1-exception-on-second-time) and [here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/27422/gpio-pin-already-exist-gpio-1-error) haven't work for me.

Thanks in advance for your help.